# Prevent container removal if it was started with --rm

Tags: docker, container

Suppose I start a container like this:

```bsh
docker run --rm -it foo sh
```

When I'm done with it it'll be removed automatically (`--rm`).

Sometimes I start a container that way, customize it and perform some work. Only then I'd realize my mistake - that once I exit the container, it will be removed.

Is it possible to override my `--rm` request once the container is started?

Comment: Just commit the container to an image?

Comment: @muru How do I do that?

Comment: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/commit/

Comment: @muru Thanks! In your opinion that is the only way?